# What is the local API endpoint, for a serverless REST API that uses the firebase emulator and node JS / Express?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a serverless REST API that uses NodeJS and Google Cloud Functions (Firebase). It works on production. But not locally for testing.

The app was created following the tutorial at: https://dev.to/levivm/creating-a-serverless-rest-api-using-google-cloud-functions-firebasefirestore-in-10-min-37km

When the firebase emulator is started locally the API endpoint seems not to work, and an error is returned:

```
URL http://my_local_server:8080/api/v1/my_api_route.
Output: Cannot GET /api/v1/my_api_route
```

The root url returns: http://my_local_server:8080/

```
{"status":"alive"}
```

Do you know what might cause the issue?

```
$ firebase emulators:start --only functions
i emulators: Starting emulators: functions
✔ functions: Using node@10 from host.
✔ functions: Emulator started at 0.0.0.0:8080
i functions: Watching "/home/ubuntu/environment/Crew-IQ/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠ functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
✔ functions[webApi]: http function initialized (0.0.0.0:8080/crew-iq/us-central1/w...).
✔ All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

Comment: What is `http://my_local_server:8080/`?  The CLI is giving you the endpoint right there in its output.  It always runs on localhost.

Comment: Thanks the endpoint works fine now. : )  My setup is on AWS Cloud 9. my_local_server is a placeholder for my subdomain which is resolved to the EC2 instance / server via AWS Route 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that application, the endpoint would be

```
http://localhost:8080/crew-iq/us-central1/webApi/api/v1/my_api_route
       └───┬───┘ └─┬┘ └──┬──┘ └────┬────┘ └──┬─┘└─────────┬────────┘
          host     │     │         │         │            │
                  port   │         │         │            │
                    project ID     │         │            │
                             function region │            │
                                         function name    │
                                                  your express app
```